# Magento 2 edit {{var alertGrid|raw}}

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2.6, alert, notification

How can I edit the `{{var alertGrid|raw}}` for the magento 2.2.x stock alert email?

I know the template is found in `vendor\magento\module-product-alert\view\frontend\email\stock_alert.html` but the template references the variable.

I want to remove the product price from the grid.

It appears to be defined here: [M2 Product Alert Email](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/069d5cd756e078030e333b7f6ab16d1b0b9bfb36/app/code/Magento/ProductAlert/Model/Email.php#L380), however, I don't see a straightforward way of editing the layout or removing the price.

Alternatively, I could remove the variable from the template, but how do I add back the product name and link to the product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alertGrid` block is rendered using  the template  `/view/frontend/templates/email/price.phtml` from the `Magento_ProductAlert` module.
you can just copy this file to your theme keeping the same path and remove the price from it.
The price is rendered but the lines:

```
<?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                $_product,
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_EMAIL,
                [
                    'display_label' => __('Price:')
                ]
            );
            ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems `/view/frontend/templates/email/stock.phtml` is actually the most appropriate file to copy as I need to edit stock alerts, not price alerts.

Comment: I tried to override stock.phtml. However the local file text is not reflecting. Any insights?